# Reload data from server angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid, angular-router, ag-grid-ng2

I display a table with [ag grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/). In order to display it I have the onGridReady in the app.component.ts:

```
  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
    this.rowData = this.api.getAllExperiments(
      this.route.snapshot.params["browse"]
    );
  }
```

Then the html to build the table is like this:

```
  <ag-grid-angular 
    #agGrid 
    id="myGrid" 
    style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" 
    class="ag-theme-balham" 
    [rowData]="rowData | async"
    [enableSorting]="true" 
    [animateRows]="true" 
    [floatingFilter]="true" 
    [enableColResize]="true" 
    [pagination]="true"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [sortingOrder]="sortingOrder"
    (rowClicked)='onRowClicked($event)'
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
  </ag-grid-angular>
```

This works properly.

As you can see in order to get the data from the server I am calling my service taking in account a parameter in the url address, like this:

**this.rowData = this.api.getAllExperiments(
  this.route.snapshot.params["browse"]
);**

The parameter can be public or private and the url address is like:

> http://localhost:4200/experiments/public

And it is defined in the router like this:

```
  {
    path: 'experiments/:browse',
    component: ExperimentsListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Experiments List' }
  },
```

This parameter allows to fetch different experiments from the server according to which button is pressed in the nav-bar.

However, given that, the component is already load, it doesn't refresh the data from the server.
How could I make the data refresh ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on GitHub. There is no need to change the components, the router or whatever. The only thing to add is in the **ngOnInit()** in the  **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(public router: Router,) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function(){
      return false;
  };

  this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
      if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          this.router.navigated = false;
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      }
  });

  }
}
```

*Answer found on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13831) thanks to mihaicux2.*

Comment: you could shared the github link for reference. also, it 's not promptly identifiable which things you have *changed*

Comment: That's the point. You don't need to change anything. You just need to add this to the app.component.ts which is the base of your angular app. @Paritosh